# SQL - Sum last value by date of current week

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to do a SUM of the last value (by date) of each day of the current week. To test I have a table with the values:

```
5 for 2023-01-12 16:53:01
2 for 2023-01-12 08:49:03
5 for 2023-01-11 08:58:19
```

I expect a result of 10.

I'm trying with the following code:

```
SELECT SUM(value) AS weeklyValue
        FROM (
            SELECT value
            FROM table
            WHERE WEEK(DATE(DataOra)) = WEEK(NOW())
            AND WEEKDAY(DATE(DataOra)) >= 1
            AND WEEKDAY(DATE(DataOra)) <= 7
            AND DataOra = (SELECT MAX(DataOra) FROM table WHERE WEEKDAY(DataOra) = WEEKDAY(DATE(DataOra)) )
            GROUP BY WEEKDAY(DATE(DataOra))
        ) AS subquery;
```

but the result is 5. Where is the mistake? Thanks

Comment: `each day of the current week` ?? So why `AND WEEKDAY(DATE(DataOra)) >= 1 AND WEEKDAY(DATE(DataOra)) <= 7` which is Tuesday to Sunday +1

Comment: you are right, I edited with AND WEEKDAY(DATE(DataOra)) >= 0 AND WEEKDAY(DATE(DataOra)) <= 6 . So should be monday->sunday . BTW, I have the same problem, still 5 is the output

Comment: I also wonder why you bother with those 2 criteria at all, as you already have the `WEEK()` specified

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I found a solution:

```
SELECT SUM(Value) AS energiaSettimanale
        FROM (
            SELECT MAX(Value) as value, WEEKDAY(DataOra) as d
            FROM table
            WHERE WEEK(DATE(DataOra)) = WEEK(NOW())
            AND WEEKDAY(DATE(DataOra)) >= 0
            AND WEEKDAY(DATE(DataOra)) <= 6
            GROUP BY d
        ) AS subquery;
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the solution because he wants the last value of the day and not the maximum value. If I understood correctly

Answer (score 1):

If I really understood what you want, this request may be (if I understood correctly, I am specifying) the solution

```
select sum(value) from `table` 
inner join ( 
 select max(DataOra) as maxDataOra 
 from `table` 
 where WEEK(DATE(DataOra))=WEEK(NOW()) 
 group by WEEKDAY(DataOra)  
) 
as tmp on DataOra=tmp.maxDataOra
```

The trick to find the most recent date of the day being to group by day number with the max() function on dateTime Data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `inner join` as follows :

```
select weekNumber, sum(value) from (
  select t.value, week(s.maxDataOra) as weekNumber
  from _table t
  inner join (
    select MAX(DataOra) as maxDataOra
    from _table
    group by DATE(DataOra)
  ) as s on s.maxDataOra = t.DataOra
) as b
group by weekNumber;
```

Check it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/hadzywwh

Answer (score 0):

> I need to do a SUM of the last value (by date) of each day of the current week.

So, let's start by constraining our working set to just the current week's data -

```
WHERE `DataOra` >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL(WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)) DAY) /* first day of current week (Mon - Sun) */
AND `DataOra` < (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL(WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)) DAY + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) /* first day of next week (Mon - Sun) */
```

Then we can use that to constrain the query used to get the MAX(DataOra) per DATE(DataOra) and join back to the original dataset to get the sum of the respective `Value`s -

```
SELECT SUM(`Value`) `energiaSettimanale`
FROM `table` `t1`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(`DataOra`) AS `maxDataOra`
    FROM `table`
    WHERE `DataOra` >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL(WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)) DAY) /* first day of current week (Mon - Sun) */
    AND `DataOra` < (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL(WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)) DAY + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) /* first day of next week (Mon - Sun) */
    GROUP BY DATE(`DataOra`)
) `t2` ON `t2`.`maxDataOra` = `t1`.`DataOra`;
```

Or if using MySQL >= 8.0 you could use the [ROW_NUMBER() window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) -

```
SELECT SUM(`Value`) `energiaSettimanale`
FROM (
    SELECT `Value`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(`DataOra`) ORDER BY `DataOra` DESC) `rn`
    FROM `table`
    WHERE `DataOra` >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL(WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)) DAY) /* first day of current week (Mon - Sun) */
    AND `DataOra` < (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL(WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE)) DAY + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) /* first day of next week (Mon - Sun) */
) `t`
WHERE `rn` = 1;
```